# Wordpress: Turn off login verification on post view page

Tags: php, wordpress, visibility, posts

Now when I want visit unpublished post page by direct URL like `http://.../?p=123` I see 404 error page. Where in code I must to perform fixes to show posts for all guests and visitors undependable from post status.

Comment: Why not make them `published` in the first place? I can't see the logic behind. If it was only one post, but you want all unplublished to behave as published, is this it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you wish to do it manually without a plugin.

1. Goto Wordpress>wp-includes
2. Open query.php in a text editor
3. Search for something like `$status = get_post_status($this->posts[0]);`
4. Replace it with `$status='publish';`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a plugin called  [Public Post Preview.](http://wordpress.org/plugins/public-post-preview/)

It adds an additional meta box called Public Post Preview. If you check the enable public preview box, then you will be given a URL which you can use.

Comment: Ok, I installed this plugin, but I can't find it in WP :)

Comment: Ok, I see, but it required manually set checkbox for all posts. But I need to show all posts this way.